# paste fails when try to run wiith excel multiple instances

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 instances of Excel-vba running at same time. Sometimes, just sometimes, the Copy & paste fails. When fails, I just run this part of the code again and it runs well. It can happen with any Paste method of my code.

I know that it happens just with multiple instances of excel, I want to know why. Glad for help!

```
'Copy to a new Sheet
Call findAndSelectRange("Fabricante", "Grand Total", 5) ' make one selection
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("FFQ.xlsm").Activate
Sheets.Add After:=Workbooks(WORKBOOK_MAIN).Sheets(Workbooks(WORKBOOK_MAIN).Sheets.count)
ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName1
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Select (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a lot of selecting and activating rather than just referencing the workbooks/sheets/cells you need which is probably mucking things up.

It's a bit hard on saying how to treat the result of your `FindAndSelectRange` procedure - although I think this would be better as a `FindAndReferenceRange` function which returns a range object.

Hopefully you can pick something useful out of the code below (note I don't select or activate anything).

```
Sub Test1()

    'Variables to hold references to both workbooks and new worksheet.
    Dim WORKBOOK_MAIN As Workbook
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    'Set references to workbooks.
    Set WORKBOOK_MAIN = ThisWorkbook
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks("FFQ.xlsm")
    'Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("fullpath & name")

    'Create new sheet and set reference to it.
    wrkBk.Worksheets.Add After:=wrkBk.Worksheets(wrkBk.Worksheets.Count)
    Set wrkSht = wrkBk.Worksheets(wrkBk.Worksheets.Count)

    'Copy cell from B2 to A2.
    'The info before `Copy` could be returned by your `findAndSelectRange` function.
    'If the function returns a valid range reference you could just write:
    'findAndSelectRange("Fabricante", "Grand Total", 5).Copy Destination:=wrkSht.Range("A2")
    WORKBOOK_MAIN.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Copy _
        Destination:=wrkSht.Range("A2")

    'If you're only interested in the unformatted value you could use:
    'wrkSht.Range("A2") = findAndSelectRange("Fabricante", "Grand Total", 5).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this solve the problem. The copyboard is shared, a quite dangerous use it in multiple instances.